# How can I stop iframe autoplay when using files from local computer?

Tags: javascript, iframe, autoplay

I'm using FlexSlider2 and I am putting videos from youtube and from my uploaded files. Iframe plays both videos, the problem is, the uploaded file is in autoplay. How can I remove the autoplay? (The youtube video is not in autoplay)

Here's the code for the one with the file from my computer.

```
<iframe id="player_1" src="uploads/video/1401328091video.mp4" width="363.5" style="margin-top:3%;" height="280" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Have you tried using the [`<video>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) element instead of iframe?

Comment: Yes, but the problem with the `<video>` tag is it won't show if there's not at least one video from youtube.

Comment: you need to conditionally output a video tag or an iframe for youtube.

Comment: I was using this code for the files in my uploads folder before I used iframe. But it won't show if there's no youtube video.
`<?php
foreach($video as $v){
 if($v['videolink']){ //youtube link detected
 //code for youtube iframe
 }else{ ?>
 <video id="player_1" width="345" height="300" controls  style="margin-top:-2.4%;margin-left:2%">
 <source src="uploads/video/1401328091video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 <source src="uploads/video/1401328091video.mp4" type="video/ogg">
 Your browser does not support the video tag.
 </video>
<?php
 }
}
?>`